# broke my 'ls' command (and few more)

Tags: command-line, ls

This is how my `ls` command looks like now in `htop`:

[image]

Also, when I try to run `ls` (or `gimp` or `libreoffice`) I get running `stegsolve` app that I can't reinstall (even found `stegsolve` binaries).

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
DATE: 06/17/21
TIME:20:48:39
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/andrii/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.fabdep/bin:/home/andrii/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/andrii/.local/bin:/home/andrii/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/cargo:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

```
$ env
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/andrii-Aspire-51G:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3876,unix/andrii-Aspire-51G:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3876
WINDOWID=46137351
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
NVM_INC=/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/include/node
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
HISTSIZE=10000
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F %T 
SHELL_SESSION_ID=b9c73238c59446979b4
DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/andrii/.gtkrc:/home/andrii/.config/gtkrc
XCURSOR_SIZE=0
GTK_MODULES=appmenu-gtk-module
XDG_SEAT=seat0
PWD=/home/andrii
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=plasma
LOGNAME=andrii
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
PATH_TO_FX=/home/andrii/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xauth-1000-_0
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/andrii
GDM_LANG=en_US
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/andrii/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/andrii/.config/gtkrc-2.0
HOME=/home/andrii
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.30
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/3
PROFILEHOME=
PROMPT_COMMAND=_direnv_hook;history -a; history -n; date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y%nTIME:%H:%M:%S'
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
KONSOLE_VERSION=191203
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
NVM_DIR=/home/andrii/.nvm
HSTR_CONFIG=hicolor
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system
USER=andrii
COLORFGBG=15;0
KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
XDG_VTNR=7
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PS1=[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ 
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
XCURSOR_THEME=Darkbolt-cursor
GCC_COLORS=error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/plasma:/home/andrii/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
PATH=/home/andrii/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.fabdep/bin:/home/andrii/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/andrii/.local/bin:/home/andrii/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/cargo:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
GDMSESSION=plasma
HISTFILESIZE=10000
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
NVM_BIN=/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
GOPATH=/home/andrii/go
_=/usr/bin/env
```

This is how my `ls` command looks like now in `htop`:

[image]

Also, when I try to run `ls` (or `gimp` or `libreoffice`) I get running `stegsolve` app that I can't reinstall (even found `stegsolve` binaries).

```
$ cat /etc/os-release
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="20.04.2 LTS (Focal Fossa)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS"
VERSION_ID="20.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=focal
UBUNTU_CODENAME=focal
DATE: 06/17/21
TIME:20:48:39
```

```
$ echo $PATH
/home/andrii/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.fabdep/bin:/home/andrii/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/andrii/.local/bin:/home/andrii/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/cargo:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
```

```
$ env
SHELL=/bin/bash
SESSION_MANAGER=local/andrii-Aspire-51G:@/tmp/.ICE-unix/3876,unix/andrii-Aspire-51G:/tmp/.ICE-unix/3876
WINDOWID=46137351
COLORTERM=truecolor
XDG_CONFIG_DIRS=/etc/xdg/xdg-plasma:/etc/xdg
XDG_SESSION_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Session0
NVM_INC=/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/include/node
HISTCONTROL=ignorespace
HISTSIZE=10000
LANGUAGE=en_US
LC_ADDRESS=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_NAME=uk_UA.UTF-8
GIT_PS1_SHOWDIRTYSTATE=1
HISTTIMEFORMAT=%F %T 
SHELL_SESSION_ID=b9c73238c59446979b4
DESKTOP_SESSION=plasma
LC_MONETARY=uk_UA.UTF-8
GTK_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk/gtkrc:/home/andrii/.gtkrc:/home/andrii/.config/gtkrc
XCURSOR_SIZE=0
GTK_MODULES=appmenu-gtk-module
XDG_SEAT=seat0
PWD=/home/andrii
XDG_SESSION_DESKTOP=plasma
LOGNAME=andrii
XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
PATH_TO_FX=/home/andrii/Downloads/javafx-sdk-11.0.2/lib
XAUTHORITY=/tmp/xauth-1000-_0
XDG_GREETER_DATA_DIR=/var/lib/lightdm-data/andrii
GDM_LANG=en_US
GTK2_RC_FILES=/etc/gtk-2.0/gtkrc:/home/andrii/.gtkrc-2.0:/home/andrii/.config/gtkrc-2.0
HOME=/home/andrii
LC_PAPER=uk_UA.UTF-8
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LS_COLORS=rs=0:di=01;34:ln=01;36:mh=00:pi=40;33:so=01;35:do=01;35:bd=40;33;01:cd=40;33;01:or=40;31;01:mi=00:su=37;41:sg=30;43:ca=30;41:tw=30;42:ow=34;42:st=37;44:ex=01;32:*.tar=01;31:*.tgz=01;31:*.arc=01;31:*.arj=01;31:*.taz=01;31:*.lha=01;31:*.lz4=01;31:*.lzh=01;31:*.lzma=01;31:*.tlz=01;31:*.txz=01;31:*.tzo=01;31:*.t7z=01;31:*.zip=01;31:*.z=01;31:*.dz=01;31:*.gz=01;31:*.lrz=01;31:*.lz=01;31:*.lzo=01;31:*.xz=01;31:*.zst=01;31:*.tzst=01;31:*.bz2=01;31:*.bz=01;31:*.tbz=01;31:*.tbz2=01;31:*.tz=01;31:*.deb=01;31:*.rpm=01;31:*.jar=01;31:*.war=01;31:*.ear=01;31:*.sar=01;31:*.rar=01;31:*.alz=01;31:*.ace=01;31:*.zoo=01;31:*.cpio=01;31:*.7z=01;31:*.rz=01;31:*.cab=01;31:*.wim=01;31:*.swm=01;31:*.dwm=01;31:*.esd=01;31:*.jpg=01;35:*.jpeg=01;35:*.mjpg=01;35:*.mjpeg=01;35:*.gif=01;35:*.bmp=01;35:*.pbm=01;35:*.pgm=01;35:*.ppm=01;35:*.tga=01;35:*.xbm=01;35:*.xpm=01;35:*.tif=01;35:*.tiff=01;35:*.png=01;35:*.svg=01;35:*.svgz=01;35:*.mng=01;35:*.pcx=01;35:*.mov=01;35:*.mpg=01;35:*.mpeg=01;35:*.m2v=01;35:*.mkv=01;35:*.webm=01;35:*.ogm=01;35:*.mp4=01;35:*.m4v=01;35:*.mp4v=01;35:*.vob=01;35:*.qt=01;35:*.nuv=01;35:*.wmv=01;35:*.asf=01;35:*.rm=01;35:*.rmvb=01;35:*.flc=01;35:*.avi=01;35:*.fli=01;35:*.flv=01;35:*.gl=01;35:*.dl=01;35:*.xcf=01;35:*.xwd=01;35:*.yuv=01;35:*.cgm=01;35:*.emf=01;35:*.ogv=01;35:*.ogx=01;35:*.aac=00;36:*.au=00;36:*.flac=00;36:*.m4a=00;36:*.mid=00;36:*.midi=00;36:*.mka=00;36:*.mp3=00;36:*.mpc=00;36:*.ogg=00;36:*.ra=00;36:*.wav=00;36:*.oga=00;36:*.opus=00;36:*.spx=00;36:*.xspf=00;36:
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=KDE
KONSOLE_DBUS_SERVICE=:1.30
KONSOLE_DBUS_SESSION=/Sessions/3
PROFILEHOME=
PROMPT_COMMAND=_direnv_hook;history -a; history -n; date '+DATE: %m/%d/%y%nTIME:%H:%M:%S'
XDG_SEAT_PATH=/org/freedesktop/DisplayManager/Seat0
KONSOLE_VERSION=191203
GOROOT=/usr/local/go
KDE_SESSION_UID=1000
NVM_DIR=/home/andrii/.nvm
HSTR_CONFIG=hicolor
LESSCLOSE=/usr/bin/lesspipe %s %s
XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
TERM=xterm-256color
LC_IDENTIFICATION=uk_UA.UTF-8
LESSOPEN=| /usr/bin/lesspipe %s
LIBVIRT_DEFAULT_URI=qemu:///system
USER=andrii
COLORFGBG=15;0
KDE_SESSION_VERSION=5
PAM_KWALLET5_LOGIN=/run/user/1000/kwallet5.socket
DISPLAY=:0
SHLVL=1
NVM_CD_FLAGS=
LC_TELEPHONE=uk_UA.UTF-8
LC_MEASUREMENT=uk_UA.UTF-8
XDG_VTNR=7
UBUNTU_MENUPROXY=1
XDG_SESSION_ID=c2
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
PS1=[\u@\h \W$(__docker_machine_ps1)]\$ 
LC_TIME=uk_UA.UTF-8
QT_AUTO_SCREEN_SCALE_FACTOR=0
XCURSOR_THEME=Darkbolt-cursor
GCC_COLORS=error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01
XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/plasma:/home/andrii/.local/share/flatpak/exports/share:/var/lib/flatpak/exports/share:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
KDE_FULL_SESSION=true
PATH=/home/andrii/kde/src/kdesrc-build:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin:/home/andrii/.cargo/bin:/home/andrii/.fabdep/bin:/home/andrii/go/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/home/andrii/.local/bin:/home/andrii/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/bin/cargo:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin:/usr/local/go/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/sbin:/sbin
GDMSESSION=plasma
HISTFILESIZE=10000
DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/1000/bus
NVM_BIN=/home/andrii/.nvm/versions/node/v12.16.1/bin
LC_NUMERIC=uk_UA.UTF-8
GOPATH=/home/andrii/go
_=/usr/bin/env
```

`type -a ls`
https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/d8wdQNsvbG/

Comment: What is the output of `type -a ls`? Why do you want to reinstall stegsolve? What errors are you getting?

Comment: update main topic with `type -a ls` output

Comment: @Kulfy looks like I got it `ls -l /home/andrii/bin/ls`
`-rwxrwxr-x 1 andrii andrii 312271 May 27  2011 /home/andrii/bin/ls`

Comment: Is your `/bin/ls` working correctly? Have you got any idea what is written to `/home/andrii/bin/ls` and how it was written there (seems to be created 2011, or is it a typing error, should be 2021)?

Comment: @Kulfy now gimp and libreoffice start's normally. Thanks

Comment: @sudodus it was zim archive with content of `stegsolve` java app

Comment: misstypo:  *zim=zip

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there was a zip archive in `/home/andrii/bin/ls` and allias that link `ls` to this location/archive.  So just delete `/home/andrii/bin/ls` file

Comment: Thanks for sharing your solution

Comment: thnks @Kufy for help to find this solution :)